# About Xtify Push Notifications are coming using GCM service

Tags: android

I am an Android Developer, I m using Xtify for push notification.
When i was working with xtify i used C2DM but as on xtify's site C2DM is deprecated and people have started using GCM service.I had read the documentation, where there is an option called Migration.In migration, we just have to replace user id with app key which i did but still i m not getting the notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xtify released their GCM version of the Android SDK which replaces C2DM.  You can download a copy with a sample app on the developer site. [Xtify SDK Downloads](http://developer.xtify.com/display/sdk/Download+the+Xtify+SDKs)